# I don't understand working of the program

Tags: javascript, object

I am learning objects in JavaScript and I don't understand methods assigned as property to objects, when objects are defined through user-defined functions.

This is a code snippet from tutorial point.com/JavaScript

```html
<script type = "text/javascript">
   function addPrice(amount) {
      with(this){
               price = amount;
          }
      }
   function book(title, author) {
      this.title = title;
      this.author = author;
      this.price = 0;
      this.addPrice = addPrice;  
     }
</script>   
 <script type = "text/javascript">
   var myBook = new book("Perl", "Mohtashim");
   myBook.addPrice(100);         
   document.write("Book title is : " + myBook.title + "<br>");
   document.write("Book author is : " + myBook.author + "<br>");
   document.write("Book price is : " + myBook.price + "<br>");
</script>
```

I want to know how the `this.addPrice = addPrice` is working and why if I remove the line no output is shown?

Comment: yes, it's the same snippet from tutorialspoint

Comment: `this.addPrice = addPrice` adds the function addPrice to the object when the object `myBook` is constructed. If you remove the line, calling the function on the object will fail with a javascript error that you can see in the javascript console.

Comment: FWIW, `with(...)` is highly discouraged. If a tutorial is still using it, find another tutorial.

Comment: You could do away with addPrice and then in you book constructor / function define it with this.addPrice = function(amount) { this.price = amount; }

Comment: First thing to understand in JavaScript is that everything is an object.  If something hasn't been assigned a value and it is referenced then the value returned will be "undefined".

Answer (score 2):

JS is pretty flexible language. In JS this:

```js
var obj = {
  name: "Raju Ritigya",
  sayHi: function() {
    console.log("hello, I'm " + this.name);
  }
};
```

Is the same as this:

```js
var obj = {};
obj.name = "Raju Ritigya";
obj.sayHi = function() {
  console.log("hello, I'm " + this.name);
};
```

Basically, there are two ways of adding properties and methods to an object in JS.

With that being said, your course is teaching you how to write "Classes", constructors and `this` in JS. IMO if you're just starting with JS, this is too complex to understand. JS doesn't support Classes natively and it tries to mimic them with prototype inheritance.

**But anyway, here's my 0.02$ on what's going on there**

In JS you have primitive types (*string, number, boolean, symbol, null, undefined*) and everything else is an object (*yes, array is an object, function is an object, object is an object*).

Primitive values are passed around by value and they are immutable, but objects are passed by reference (*a point in memory*) and they are mutable

```js
var foo = {};
var bar = {};
console.log(foo === bar) //false
```

Even though `foo` and `bar` look the same, they point to different places in memory, hence for JS they are not the same!

```js
var foo = {};
var bar = foo;
bar.name = "random name";
console.log(foo.name); // "random name"
```

And now `foo` and `bar` point to the same reference and making changes to one of them reflect to the other one.

In JS every function needs to return something. If you don't explicitly put a `return` statement in your function it will return `undefined` and if you use `new` keyword in front of your function call, it will return a new object that will have that function as a constructor.

So, in conclusion, what's going on there is that you have a constructor (*book*) that's gonna return an object with 3 properties (*author, title, price*) and a method (*addPrice*). That method is a function (and as we already said, functions are objects in JS and can be easily passed around). It would be exactly the same if you wrote your constructor like this:

```js
function book(title, author) {
  this.title = title;
  this.author = author;
  this.price = 0;
  this.addPrice = function(amount) {
    this.price = amount
  };
}
```

As @deceze mentioned, using `with` is highly discouraged.

By removing the `this.addPrice = addPrice` line, you don't add a method to your object but later on you try to call it on this line `myBook.addPrice(100);`

Your code breaks on that line and JS won't continue executing the rest of your program (you can open `console` tab in `dev tools` and see the error there).

Hope it helps, 
Cheers!

Comment: Thanks,for your elaborate answer